# Applications of the countable omitting types theorem

Tags: model-theory

I am currently studying the countable Omitting Types Theorem (as presented by Hodges in his book about Model theory):

Let $L$ be a countable first-order language, $T$ a theory in $L$ which has a model, and for each $ m < \omega $ let $\Phi_m$ be an unsupported set over $T$ in $L$. Then $T$ has a model which omits all the sets $\Phi_m$.

Hodges states that the Omitting Types Theorem has different applications but I couldn't find many yet. A professor I talked to also told me about its importance but did not mention anything specific. So I wanted to ask about different applications of it in model theory, but also in other branches of mathematics.

Comment: "Many different application" sounds bragging. Though the OTT is fundamental for the proof of the Theorem of Engeler, Ryll-Nardzewsky, and Svenonius, it does not play a big role in model theory. I would be surprised to see applications in other branch of mathematics.

Comment: @PrimoPetri I agree that writing "many different applications" might be overstating the importance of the theorem, but I think writing "it does not play a big role in model theory" is understating it. Omitting Types is part of the standard model theory toolbox, and it does come up from time to time - especially in stability theory, I would say.

Comment: @AlexKruckman It's also worth keeping in mind that OTT is sufficiently basic that it makes sense for other logics besides first-order logic. A recent text which leaps to mind is [Boney on Shelah on AECs](https://people.math.harvard.edu/~wboney/notes/SOTTNotes.pdf), but let me also mention two lesser-known examples: [Grilliot's *Omitting types: application to recursion theory*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiQiOy-gb70AhXhPn0KHclWDPsQFnoECAIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jstor.org%2Fstable%2F2272549&usg=AOvVaw2lgL6gzR9Bo6SFhYM2Ddun) *(contd)*

Comment: and [Mansfield's *Omitting types: application to descriptive set theory*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiQiOy-gb70AhXhPn0KHclWDPsQFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fjournals%2Fproc%2F1975-047-01%2FS0002-9939-1975-0354371-0%2FS0002-9939-1975-0354371-0.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0bD0Qu-DbbdrIm3g4awMVL). (Whoops, I meant to tag @PrimoPetri above, but Alex may find this interesting too.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I did not know the articles you mention (I'll have a look). The OTT theorem is a version of Kuratowski-Ulam theorem. I.e. it is Baire category phenomenon... in most contests a direct proof might be more natural. The alleged "applications"  could have got notoriety by what is known as "publication bias".

Comment: @AlexKruckman (and @TQL) You are right. I had no intention to diminish the relevance of the OTT in model theory.

Comment: Forcing is closely related to the Omitting Types Theorem. I don’t know if anybody has done a systematic development of the connection between them, but if you search the literature, you’ll find many articles discussing aspects they have in common.

Comment: I tried to "correct" the question.

Comment: Belatedly, another relevant source: Barwise, "[The role of the omitting types theorem in infinitary logic](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02011633)." The focus of this paper is how OTT at a logic $\mathcal{X}$ leads to properties of the infinitary analogue $\mathcal{X}_{\omega_1,\omega}$. All of the sources I've linked are less about applying OTT to prove a specific result, and more about using OTT as a unifying theme (@PrimoPetri).